# Position div relative to its bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to position a pop-up  using its bottom attribute so that it is placed just above an element that is currently mouse-overed . Let us say:

```
$('#pop-up').css({
bottom : currentlyMouseOverElement.offset().top + "px",
});
```

The problem is that the  is displayed but not exactly above the currently mouse-overed element, rather far above it.

Is there something I am missing? Can somebody help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.
Horace

Comment: If you put a span in a div in a fieldset, then hover above the span, all three elements will receive the 'hover' status. `currentlyMouseOverElement` could be a parent element of the element you're actually hovering over. Can you check that?

Comment: the position can be quite tricky depending on the browser. Take a look at Paul Koch's page to learn more: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code for height based poition

```
 $('#pop-up').css({

  bottom : (currentlyMouseOverElement.offset().top - currentlyMouseOverElement.height())+  "px",
 });
```

Comment: Hi Murali, it still does not work, I think it has to do with the fact that the div content size is variable. I get that content per ajax request, set  it as content with  $('#pop-up').html(contentFromAjaxRequest). Do you think that the variable size is really the problem that leads that the height of the $('#pop-up') div overlaps currentlyMouseOverElement? Does setting the bottom of the $('#pop-up') div really mean: set the bottom side of the $('#pop-up') div at a position independently from its height?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide position:absolute to the popup element & position:relative to its parent.

```
$('#pop-up').css({
position: absolute,
bottom : currentlyMouseOverElement.offset().top + "px",
});
```